# how to create regex expression to replace hypen with period with this sample characters HA045141-1 to make HA04514.1

Tags: regex

I have this capture the sample characters.

```
^([A-Za-z0-9].*?)-[0-9]$
```

Comment: We need a bit more context to help you, how does your data look like, is it all hypens that you need to replace, because then `-` would do the trick, [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/J0Xt5g/1). What language or program are you using to replace the hyphen? your sample and result also removes a 1 before the hyphen should that also be removed?

Comment: We have our inhouse application in xml. I only need to make this sample characters HA045141-1 to make it to HA045141.1

Comment: sorry it was type error only replace the - with .

Comment: Try to paste in some xml, then it will be easier to help you create a regex. If you just need to replace the hyphen, then you can do something like this `([A-Za-z0-9].*?)-([0-9])` [replace example](https://regex101.com/r/Wj1cMN/1), take the two capture groups and then replace the not captured `-` with `.`

Comment: I cannot make 2 capture groups in our xml. it should be in regex  1 line statement. ^([A-Za-z0-9].*?)-[0-9]$  for this one the result is HA045141-1 because last time I only know the trimming but for this is replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to replace the hyphen in the middle of the text, then you can do something like this

```
([A-Za-z0-9].*?)-([0-9])
```

It takes the two capture groups and then replace the not captured `-` with `.`, by replacing it with `$1.$2`.

This works by taking the first part of the regex and then setting it back, and then putting in a `.` where the `-` is placed, and lastly placing the second capture group.

This will provide a match for `HA045141-1` and replace the hyphen with a dot to make  `HA045141.1`